# Problem in set theory

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $h:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $\forall x\in \mathbb R\Rightarrow h(x)>0$. Prove that there exist $A\subset \mathbb R$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that

$A=_c\mathbb R$ and $\forall x\in A\Rightarrow h(x)>\epsilon$.

What i did so far is this. By contradiction, suppose that $\forall A\subset \mathbb R$ or $\forall \epsilon >0$ we have that $A<_c\mathbb R$ and that there is a $x\in A\Rightarrow h(x)\leq \epsilon$.

Because $\forall A\subset \mathbb R\Rightarrow A<_c\mathbb R$ is false we have that  for $ A\subset \mathbb R $ and $\forall \epsilon >0\Rightarrow \exists x\in A :0<h(x)\leq \epsilon$.

Because $A<_c\mathbb R\Rightarrow A<_c\mathbb R_+$ and thus $h|_A$ cannot be a surjection. But we have that $\forall \epsilon >0\Rightarrow \exists x\in A :0<h(x)\leq \epsilon$. Does this imply that $h|_A$ is a surjection to $\mathbb R_+$?

In general i need help with this problem. Any solutions? Should i use somehow the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: The solution suggested by J.J. which relies (as you noted) on Koenig's theorem requires the axiom of choice. Without the axiom of choice it is consistent that the real numbers are a countable union of countable sets, in which case it is easy to engineer a counterexample for this statement.

Comment: (I also feel that this is a duplicate in one way or another, but I'm not 100% sure.)

Answer (score 0):

Write $\mathbb{R}$ as the countable union
$$\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \{x \in \mathbb{R} : h(x) > \frac{1}{n}\}.$$

Since $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be a countable union of sets of cardinality strictly less than $\mathbb{R}$, one of the sets must have cardinality of the continuum. (Thanks Asaf Karagila.)

Comment: Aha. So there is a $n$ such that the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : h(x) > \frac{1}{n}\}$ has cardinality equal to $c$, due to Konig's theorem. Right?

Comment: @user113576: I must admit that I'm not totally sure of this argument after all. I can see that this would work if we assumed continuum hypothesis, but my set theory skills are low and I don't know if this argument also works without it.

Comment: @user113576: Yes, that is correct; J.J. there is no need to invoke the continuum hypothesis, we can prove that the continuum cannot be the union of a countable family of sets all of which have size $<\Bbb R$. See my comment on the question itself regarding the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks, that was my hunch. How does one do that?

Comment: J.J., this is a simple corollary from Koenig's theorem. The cofinality of $2^\kappa$ has to be greater than $\kappa$; in the case of $\aleph_0$ this means exactly that.